# iPhone app to retrieve photos from Facebook profile

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, web-services

I need it to pull photos from my Facebook profile. Right now I'm working on the design/architecture of my app.

My real question is "what's the best way to pull the profiles pictures from Facebook?". Let's assume that this app would be used by hundreds of people or maybe thousands.

Would it be better to have my own server to pull the pictures from Facebook and then my server would send updates to the app? Or should the app connect directly to Facebook to retrieve the pictures?

I really don't know how this should be done. If you're an iOS expert and know how to do this please provide me with some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the needs of your app.

Pulling directly from facebook using the [facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/) is definitely simpler - and unless you have specific requirements, simpler is always better.  Resist the urge to over architect.  Keep it simple until you need more components and systems.

For example, some requirements that would require you pulling the photos server side would be:

- You want users of your app to be able to login to your application and view their information and images from your web site.
- You want to do extra processing on the images.
- You want users in your app to be able to distribute/share/expose images to others that may not have a facebook account.
- etc...

But once again, if you don't need to have a server, then don't.  First decide what you want the app to be and then come up with the architecture and sub-systems.

Answer (score 0):

The best and correct way is using the facebookSDK https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

To have a good idea and learn how o check and read the code in the samples that go with the SDK.

1. setup an facebook app, amke sure to tell it is for ios, place the
   correct bundle identifier and in permissions place all need options
2. for login and access to pictures get facebook session up and running
3. make the request